# Sync store to the proxy(REST) by clicking a button instead of AutoSync in Ext Js

Tags: extjs

I am creating CRUD operations with EXT JS(frontend) and ASP NET(backend). I already done with CREATE, READ, and DELETE. But when it comes to UPDATE, I need to sync the data by clicking a button instead of using AutoSync in store.

This is what happened if I used AutoSync.
[ASP NET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7Wyl.png)

I need to sync or update the data by clicking a button instead of AutoSync.
I also tried using Store.sync() but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `autoSync` false, then programmatically call `sync()`?